# New column adding values of different columns with strings and numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this structure (in the real one there are more columns Game x, around 30, but for explaining I think it's ok with these 2 columns):

```
      Name         Game 1            Game 2
0     Player 1     Starting 68       Starting
1     Player 2     Bench 74          Starting 80
2     Player 3     Starting          Bench
3     Player 4     Bench             Bench 50
4     Player 5     NaN               Starting
```

I need new columns for counting the minutes of any player in the columns "Game x" based in these conditions:

- Starting: means the player has played 90 minutes
- Starting 68 (or whichever): means the player has played 68 minutes (or whichever)
- Bench and NaN: means the player has played 0 minutes
- Bench 74 (or whichever): means the player has played 16 minutes (the total is 90 so he started at the minute 74 and then is 90 - 74 = 16)

There would be 2 columns counting the number of the minutes the player has played when he started the game and when he entered the game from the bench.

The final dataframe would be:

```
      Name         Game 1           Game 2           Minutes Starting   Minutes Bench
0     Player 1     Starting 68      Starting         158                0
1     Player 2     Bench 74         Starting 80      80                 16
2     Player 3     Starting         Bench            90                 0
3     Player 4     Bench            Bench 50         0                  40
4     Player 5     NaN              Starting 60      60                 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write a function that parses a text field and returns the corresponding number of minutes, you can apply that function to each game column and add up the results. For example, the time played from start:

```py
def played_from_start(entry):
    entry = str(entry)  # Without this, np.nan is a float.
    if entry == 'nan' or entry == '':
        return 0
    if entry.startswith('Bench'):
        return 0
    if entry == 'Starting':
        return 90
    if entry.startswith('Starting'):
        return int(entry[9:])
    print(f"Warning: Entry '{entry}' not recognized.")
    return np.nan


games = ['Game 1', 'Game 2']

df['Minutes Starting'] = np.sum(np.array([df[game].apply(played_from_start).values
                                          for game in games]),
                                axis=0)
```

Comment: I get the idea, but I receive an error: KeyError: 'Game 1'

Comment: Make sure that the strings in the `games` list match the respective column names in your dataframe exactly.

Comment: Also, I was assuming the name of your dataframe is `df`. You may need to substitute the actual name.

Comment: I fixed changing the name of the df... but now I get this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''     I guess it's something about converting the string to int but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: That error must result from the case `if entry.startswith('Starting'): return int(entry[9:])`. My assumption here was that if the entry starts with 'Starting', it is followed by a space and then the number of minutes, as in the example data you provided. The error indicates that in your actual data, at least one entry does not follow this format.

Comment: Great! It's because of that, there is an exceptional case of a Player with 'Starting 66 66' (I don't know why it's like this but I will try to fix it). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck when it comes to creating the function for bench players. I have checked that all the "Bench xx" values are formatted correctly but I always get the error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' It's like it doesn't recognize those numbers but it recognizes the ones that go with Starting

Comment: Note that 'Bench' has three characters less than 'Starting', so instead of `int(entry[9:])`, you will need `int(entry[6:])` this time.